# How does the smarty expression $entry@key work?

Tags: php, smarty

While reading the smarty documentation of the built-in {call}-function ([link to the specific documentation page](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.call.tpl)), I saw this code snippet (it's an example of the documentation):

```
{function name=menu level=0}
  <ul class="level{$level}">
  {foreach $data as $entry}
    {if is_array($entry)}
      <li>{$entry@key}</li>
      {call name=menu data=$entry level=$level+1}
    {else}
      <li>{$entry}</li>
    {/if}
  {/foreach}
  </ul>
{/function}
```

I'm confused by the expression

```
$entry@key
```

Can somebody explain how it works, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$variable@key` is a special syntax usable in [a `{foreach}` block](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl) which associates "properties" of the loop itself with the variable holding the current value of the loop.

In Smarty 2, you had to say `$smarty.foreach.name_of_foreach_block.name_of_property`, whereas Smarty 3 simplifies this to `$variable_from_loop@property`.

In the example given, you could also use something like `{if $entry@iteration is odd}class="odd"{else}class="even"}`, or more complex versions [as seen in the manual page](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl#foreach.property.iteration).